# NotSupportedException when casting Membership.GetAllUsers() to generic list

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-membership

I am trying to use LINQ on the .NET Membership.GetAllUsers() collection, for example when getting all usernames:

```
var usernames = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>().Select(x=>x.UserName).ToList();
```

But VS tells me that it is not supported..

Membership is a part of Web.Security, same as MembershipUser

Here is my connection string (if that is of any relevance):

```
   <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=somerserver.xx\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=bedriftsmelding;User Id=SomeUser;Password=SomePassword;Integrated Security=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Stack trace:

> System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
>   Message=Specified method is not supported.
>   Source=System.Web.Extensions   StackTrace:
>          at System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider.GetAllUsers(Int32
>   pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, Int32& totalRecords)
>          at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers(Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, Int32& totalRecords)
>          at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers()
>          at Bedriftsmelding.Nettside.Models.CompanyUsers.GetUserIdFromUserName(String
>   username) in
>   C:\Projects\Bedriftsmelding\Bedriftsmelding.Nettside\Models\CompanyUsers.cs:line
>   26
>          at Bedriftsmelding.Tests.DTO.CompanyUsersTest.TestGetUserIdFromUserName()
>   in
>   C:\Projects\Bedriftsmelding\Bedriftsmelding.Tests\DTO\CompanyUsersTest.cs:line
>   16   InnerException:

Comment: I have added it to the question, thanks

Comment: You would have to use `foreach` for that collection.

Comment: foreach did not help, no methods available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're using a ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider rather than the default SqlMembershipProvider.

According to the docs for ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, GetllAllUsers is not supported and throws a not supported exception.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.clientservices.providers.clientformsauthenticationmembershipprovider.getallusers.aspx

It appears that only the basic ValiateUser and a few other functions work with this provider, as it's designed for use with the Ajax extensions.  None of the user functions work, such as GetUser, GetAllUsers, DeleteUser, CreateUser, etc...

Comment: Hmm, that sounds plausible. How did you draw this conclusion? And how can I verify that this is really the case? And lastly, how can I change to the default provider?

Comment: @Sindre - What part of "according to the docs", and providing a link to the aforementioned docs for you to look at yourself is unclear?  I "drew this conclusion" by examining the docs and noticing where it says "This method always throws an exception." and looking at the overview that says "This method is not used by this class." about GetAllUsers.  I also noticed that it said the same thing about the other methods I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem until I read through this topic: [SimpleMembership, Membership Providers, Universal Providers and the new ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC 4 templates](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx) .

A simple answer is that the membership machanism in MVC4 is totally different from those in MVC3 and before. And there is other information from PM of asp.net MVC project. I think it is a trend and it is worth trying to rebuild my relevant codes again from the scratch.