# membership create user not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

**I've using a webService that populates the Business UI and updates the DB. But before it updates the DB I need to create the USER.**...Has anyone any idea why

```
Membership.CreateUser(user.Username,
                            System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(7, Membership.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters),
                            user.Email);
```

or

```
Membership.CreateUser(user.Username,
                            System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(7, Membership.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters),
                            user.Email,
                            null,
                            null,
                            true,
                            null,
                            out status);
```

isnt working....error is

> {System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
>
> at System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String
>   username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion,
>   String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey,
>   MembershipCreateStatus& status)
>
> at System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String
>   passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey,
>   MembershipCreateStatus& status)
>
> at System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email)

**UPDATE**
Find app.config attached

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
  <!--<providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="RFS.DotNetNuke.MembershipConnString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>-->
  <providers>
    <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="RFS.DotNetNuke.MembershipConnString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="AspNet" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
    <!--<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="AspNetConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="AspNet" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>-->
  </providers>
</membership>

<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="RFS.DotNetNuke.MembershipConnString" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<!--<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="RFS.DotNetNuke.MembershipConnString" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>-->
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true" createPersistentCookie="false" cookieProtection="All">
  <providers>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" applicationName="AspNet" connectionStringName="RFS.DotNetNuke.MembershipConnString" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

**WEBCONFIG**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
   <!--LIST OF APP SETTINGS-->

  </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings>
   <!-- LIST OF CONNECTION STRINGS -->
  </connectionStrings>


  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <machineKey validationKey="xxxx" decryptionKey="xxx" decryption="xxx" validation="xxx" />
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx"/>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DotNetNuke.MembershipConnString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" passwordFormat="Encrypted" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="DotNetNuke"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="wildfire\dev_websvc_sapeai" />

    </authorization>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      <security>
          <requestFiltering>
              <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
          </requestFiltering>
      </security>
        <defaultDocument>
          <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="default.aspx" />
            <add value="Default.htm" />
            <add value="Default.asp" />
            <add value="index.htm" />
            <add value="index.html" />
            <add value="iisstart.htm" />
          </files>
        </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!--<behavior name="Default_Behaviour">-->
            <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />

          <!-- BEGIN: Comment out these settings when running in development -->
          <!--<sqlWorkflowInstanceStore instanceCompletionAction="DeleteAll" instanceEncodingOption="None" instanceLockedExceptionAction="NoRetry" connectionStringName="ApplicationServerWorkflowInstanceStoreConnectionString" hostLockRenewalPeriod="00:00:30" runnableInstancesDetectionPeriod="00:00:05" />
          <workflowInstanceManagement authorizedWindowsGroup="AS_Administrators" />
          <workflowUnhandledException action="AbandonAndSuspend" />
          <workflowIdle timeToPersist="00:01:00" timeToUnload="00:01:00" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1" maxConcurrentSessions="1" maxConcurrentInstances="1" />
          <etwTracking profileName="Personnel Data Tracking" />-->
          <!-- END: Comment out these settings when running in development -->





        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="~/SynchronisePersonnelService.xamlx" service="SynchronisePersonnelService.xamlx" factory="WebServices.SapEai.Workflow.HostFactory"/>
        <add relativeAddress="~/SynchroniseOrganisationService.xamlx" service="SynchroniseOrganisationService.xamlx" factory="WebServices.SapEai.Workflow.HostFactory"/>
        <add relativeAddress="~/SynchroniseAD_DNN.xamlx" service="SynchroniseAD_DNN.xamlx" factory="WebServices.SapEai.Workflow.HostFactory" />
      </serviceActivations>      

    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <tracking>
      <profiles>
        <trackingProfile name="Personnel Data Tracking">
          <workflow activityDefinitionId="*">
            <workflowInstanceQueries>
              <workflowInstanceQuery>
                <states>
                  <state name="*" />
                </states>
              </workflowInstanceQuery>
            </workflowInstanceQueries>
            <activityStateQueries>
              <activityStateQuery activityName="*">
                <states>
                  <state name="*" />
                </states>
                <variables>
                  <variable name="_perNo" />
                </variables>
              </activityStateQuery>
            </activityStateQueries>
            <faultPropagationQueries>
              <faultPropagationQuery faultSourceActivityName="*" faultHandlerActivityName="*" />
            </faultPropagationQueries>
            <customTrackingQueries>
              <customTrackingQuery name="*" activityName="*" />
            </customTrackingQueries>
          </workflow>
        </trackingProfile>

      </profiles>
    </tracking>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

**NOTE**
IVE ALSO TESTED var

```
user1 = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(user.Username);
```

and this is also failing with the same error so it appears the problem is MEMBERSHIP. Has it anything to do with access? I found.`https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3855.windows-forms-application-how-to-use-a-membership-provider-of-asp-net-in.aspx`..and I tried changing the app config to suit but no such joy

Found many related Q's online but none help
eg

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905343/notsupportedexception-when-casting-membership-getallusers-to-generic-list
```

I tested the answer in the above link on the assumption that I was using using a ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider(SimpleMembership) rather than the default SqlMembershipProvider....so I tested

```
Membership.ValidateUser("john", "john");
```

which should have worked ...
but this failed with...

```
{System.ArgumentException: The serviceUri configuration setting was not found.

       at System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider.GetServiceUri()
```

Also tried updating the app.config file from the `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/common-client-technologies/how-to-configure-client-application-services`

Another post tells me to try built-in Windows security i..https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7447d184-adab-42d3-843a-02e992baadcc/how-to-use-membership-and-role-provider-in-a-window-app?forum=netfxbcl

so I tried  `var user1 = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(user.Username);` but this failed with System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at

```
System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider.GetUser(String
```

It also said in that article to reuse the API and interfaces to create your own subsystem...Can anyone give me a start on this? i know what I have to do just need a hand implementing it thank you(please see below link)

Is this what I should be doing?

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479046.aspx
```

Comment: I think you need to speak to Martin... :-)

Comment: @John Could you show us the web.config file?

Comment: @Win thanks for the reply....please see updated Q for what you asked along with extra info...thank you